# Requirejs “noext!” plugin alternative to "text!" plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, requirejs

I'm using the noext plugin for preventing the requirejs from adding the .js at the end of files. However when I see the usage of the plugin: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/examples/noext.html , I'm wondering if its an alternative to text! plugin, since its used in a very similar way text! plugin is used?
Any ideas if  "noext!" plugin can be used instead of text! plugin to load templates or to needs both to be used??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you are looking at, the `noext` plugin is loading modules of the form:

```
define(function(){
    return {
        msg : 'foo loaded!'
    };
});
```

Presumably you could shove a template in `msg` and then use `noext` to load it.

With the `text` plugin you could load a file that contains only the text:

```
foo loaded!
```

What `text` shares with `noext` is that it does not add an extension to the module names given to it.

Comment: The file you are trying to load there does not use `define`, so no.

Comment: sorry but i still dont get as how can i load my text.mu file using the noext plugin? I went through the usage above you mentioned in github, but im still confused how to load any template using the noext plugin. Are there any more examples you may have come across?

Comment: i tried doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/yobsdoa6/1/    didnt quite work, gave me a cross origin policy error